# Downstairs WC cold - Extractor or windows?

Tags: heating, toilet, ventilation, exhaust-fan

I have a new build and of course there will be a few niggles here and there, however one of the biggest gripes is that the downstairs WC (toilet) feels chilly when compared with the hallway just the other side of the door.

I have some temperature probes that I have left in the hallway and in the WC itself, with data to show the disparity.

[image]

I am wondering what th issue will be here.

There is a an extractor fan, something cheap and simple such as [Manrose mg100t 100mm Fan](https://www.screwfix.com/p/manrose-mg100t-100mm-axial-bathroom-extractor-fan-with-timer-white-240v/62530)
[image]

it appears to have been just fitted to a tube to the outside with a basic grid out there, to which when the wind is up I can feel a breeze and pressure blowing the cold air into the room.

I pleaded with the developers and they have since tried 'balancing' the radiators a bit and have also fitted a flappy louvred cowelling to the outside of the extractor which does appear to have cut down on the draftiness.

However, it does appear that the temperature is much better given the heating having been on this afternoon:
[image]

[image]

Is there anything I can do to help improve the situation?

- I have read about extractor fans that have shutters built in to the design, but I'm not sure if they will be any better.
- Could it be the window itself?

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Is the WC heated by a heater or a heat vent?  If by vent, duct work might need tuning(more to WC, less somewhere else).  New build should have same window type as other rooms, but draft might be there.  Is the door left open or close?

Comment: I don't know what is WC, but I prefer a solid flipper on the exhaust over a louver which can misfunction due to dust buildup.

Comment: @r13  Think it stands for water closet, also known as the loo.  For North Americans a bathroom.

Comment: Apologies, I thought WC was universal for toilet.